# Excel search function - match case

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find if cells have specific string or not. This is how I do it right now:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA";L2)); "yes"; "no")
```

If a cell has "AAA", I write to another cell yes, if not, I write no...

The problem is that it also gets true answer for AAA1 or AAA1234 for an example, how can I return true statement only for AAA?

If there are trailing numbers/charcters in my string, I want to reutrn no, but the cell itself might be longer... for and example "AAA BVC BFD2" etc. Then I want to return true. False if for an example: "AAA1 BVC BFD2"

Comment: what do you mean by `return true statement only for AAA`? when cell's value _is_ `AAA` or contains _word_ `AAA`?

Comment: @Badr Hari - it sounds like you do not want to `search` for a substring, but rather want to test if the cell value is `=` to "AAA"? Can you use `=IF(TRIM(L2)="AAA";"yes";"no")` instead?

Comment: simoco - it was a typo, I corrected myself.
@Roberto - no, because in the cell there might be other text also.

Comment: @BadrHari - sorry, I still don't get it. If there is "other text" (like trailing numbers), your example says you want it to return "no". So checking for equality would produce this result.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question probably very bad... if there are trailing numbers/charcters in my string, I want to reutrn no, but the cell itself might be longer... for and example "AAA BVC BFD2" etc. Then I want to return true. False if for an example: "AAA1 BVC BFD2"

Comment: @BadrHari, try `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" AAA ";" " & L2 & " ")); "yes"; "no")`

Comment: This really does work, but how and what does it to? Also if you would write it as answer, I would be able to accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you can use this one:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" AAA ";" " & L2 & " ")); "yes"; "no")
```

**How it works:**

1. suppose you have a string `"AAA BVC BFD2"` in cell `L2`.
2. `" " & L2 & " "` part modifies this string to `" AAA BVC BFD2 "` (note, there're additional spaces in the end and in the beggining)
3. now, we're able to search `" AAA "` (with spaces) in modified string `" " & L2 & " "`.

Comment: Thank you, very good answer, don't you happen to know how can I use or statement with that function? Lets say AAA or BBB ?

Comment: use this formula `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" AAA ";" BBB "};" " & L2 & " "))); "yes"; "no")`. This is an _array formula_, so type the formula then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm clearly missing something as it seems to me that you could do this with something as simple as

=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="AAA ","yes","no")

I don't think the question is particularly clear, if I'm being honest...